# How to convert C++/CLI array to String or standard C array

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a managed array:

```
array<unsigned char>^ myGcArray;
```

Assume the array is null terminated. I want to display the contents using `Console::WriteLine()`. What's the easiest way to convert `myGcArray` to `String` ?

One of the constructors to `String` has a parameter of `const char*`, so if I can convert `myGcArray` to that, then it would work too. How should I do that?

I can copy the contents of `myGcArray` to a regular `unsigned char myarray[]`, but is that the best way?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to use the proper encoding.  If you have no idea then get started with String^ str = System::Text::Encoding::Default->GetString(myGcArray);

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. That's exactly what I needed. Sorry I'm unable to upvote your comment. My account is new.

Comment: A null-terminated, counted array is a bit odd. Are null characters in the array part of your data? If so, good: `GetString()` will make them characters in your string (which is also counted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have to use the proper encoding. If you have no idea then get started with

```
String^ str = System::Text::Encoding::Default->GetString(myGcArray);
```

by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321646/how-to-convert-c-cli-array-to-string-or-standard-c-array#comment43102637_27321646)